# Decrement the previous data count, if present sending data is same as previous

Tags: java, mysql, oracle11g

Suppose i have list of data(oracle MY_SQL) for example

```
 State   RPD     Mac_address        total_Mac_Online_Count.     
 26      AA      aa:bb:12:cc:ab:aa  1
 26      BB      aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ab  1
 26      CC      aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac  1
 26      DD      aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ad  1
 26      EE      aa:bb:12:cc:ab:bb  1
```

Herewith, I'm sending data like this to db

```
 26      AB      aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac
```

Mac_address is same as for RPD "CC". Now total_Mac_Online_Count should decrease by one for RPD "CC"

```
 26      CC      aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac  0
```

and for new data it should add normally like

```
 26      AB      aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac  1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Test case:

```
SQL> create table mac
  2    (state number,
  3     rpd varchar2(2),
  4     mac_address varchar2(20) constraint uk_mac unique,
  5     total_count number
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into mac
  2    select 26, 'aa', 'aa:bb:12:cc:ab:aa', 1 from dual union
  3    select 26, 'bb', 'aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ab', 1 from dual union
  4    select 26, 'cc', 'aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac', 1 from dual;

3 rows created.
```

A procedure: I'm selecting the whole row into a local variable. As you might get `NO_DATA_FOUND`, I'm handling it (by doing *nothing*). If there's a match, I'm subtracting the `TOTAL_COUNT` column value by 1 for the same MAC address row and inserting the whole new row.

However, it seems that this model supports duplicate MAC addresses. Is that legal? What do you want to do in such cases? For example, if you enter the same MAC address once again? `SELECT` will return `TOO_MANY_ROWS` which should be handled. One option is to update only one (which one?) row; or ...?

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_mac
  2    (par_state in number, par_rpd in varchar2, par_mac_address in varchar2)
  3  is
  4    l_row mac%rowtype;
  5  begin
  6    select *
  7      into l_row
  8      from mac
  9      where mac_address = par_mac_address;
 10
 11    update mac set
 12      total_count = total_count - 1
 13      where mac_address = par_mac_address;
 14
 15    insert into mac (state, rpd, mac_address, total_count)
 16    values
 17    (par_state, par_rpd, par_mac_address, 1);
 18  exception
 19    when no_data_found then null;
 20  end;
 21  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from mac;

     STATE RP MAC_ADDRESS          TOTAL_COUNT
---------- -- -------------------- -----------
        26 aa aa:bb:12:cc:ab:aa              1
        26 bb aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ab              1
        26 cc aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac              1

SQL> exec p_mac(26, 'ab', 'aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From mac;

     STATE RP MAC_ADDRESS          TOTAL_COUNT
---------- -- -------------------- -----------
        26 aa aa:bb:12:cc:ab:aa              1
        26 bb aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ab              1
        26 cc aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac              0
        26 ab aa:bb:12:cc:ab:ac              1

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, it will create multiple row with same Mac. It's a business logic. The Mac will replace in another table. It should decrease the previous Mac address total count and for current Mac(both Mac are same) address the count should be 1.